# Connection Refused when trying to access exposed port of docker container

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

I created a simple golang web application working on port 8080.

Docker file:

[image: Docker file]

When I tried on web, I got empty response error.

Then, I opened bash of the container and found something strange.
When I did curl http://localhost:8080, I received the response but when I did same on eth0 ip, it failed.

[image: CURL result]

ignore the 404. 404 means my server app is responding.

The application is accepting traffic only on localhost of the container and not accessible using docker/k8s IP.

Kindly suggest!

Comment: can you paste the image contents as text, and also show how you run the docker?

Comment: FROM golang:1.17

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./app ./

RUN go mod download && go mod verify

ENV CGO_ENABLED 0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

RUN go build -v -o /dist

RUN apt update && apt install net-tools && apt install curl

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/dist"]

Comment: you can also **exec into** the docker and try access by `127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: @LeiYang I did that already and my curl can access the server on 127.0.0.1:8080 but unable to access using k8s/docker IP. On similar note my node servers are behaving normally. This makes me wonder if there is something wrong with the go-lang base image or there is problem in the way I have composed the Dockerfile.

Comment: You add 2 tags, `google-kubernetes-engine`, `azure-aks`, you've tried on both Cloud providers or you added tags randomly? Your Kubernetes cluster is on local machine or on cloud? You are using `kubernetes`, `docker swarm` or pure `docker`? What exactly you want to achieve? Are you using any YAML with deployment or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the container with the -p flag set to allow traffic on port 8080? (Like this: `docker run -p 8080:8080 [your_image]`)

Comment: Yes, here is the command which I used to run the docker $docker run -p 8080:8080 --name go -it a2c78dceb6d8.

Comment: Then I used this command to access the shell of the container: $docker exec -it e3c4c41e895cc26a886655d94ffab001153cb84ed168e884bc447b4d95ad9a47 /bin/sh

Comment: can you paste output of `docker ps`?